# Why do VHDL attribute calls require a process?

Tags: vhdl

If I have the following VHDL-200X architecture:

```
architecture my_arc of my_entity is
    signal test_char   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal test_char_c : character;
    signal test_char_i : integer;
begin
    test_char   <= "01001010";
    test_char_i <= to_integer(unsigned(test_char));
    test_char_c <= character'val(test_char_i);
end architecture my_arc;
```

...and simulate it (in Xilinx iSim 14.1), `test_char_c` does not change from its initial value of `NUL` even though `test_char_i` takes the value `74`. If, however, I replace the last line in the architecture with:

```
    process(test_char_i)
    begin
        test_char_c <= character'val(test_char_i);
    end process;
```

...then `test_char_c` takes on the value `J` as I'd expect.

I thought that a bare signal assignment will be updated concurrently if *any* signal on the right hand side changes. In other words, it's equivalent to a process that is sensitive to all signals involved in the assignment.

Why doesn't `test_char_c` get updated in the first instance?

**Edit:** Changing `test_char_i` to a `natural` doesn't change the result.

Comment: Your thought is correct, it's a bug/non-conformance of iSim.

Comment: @wap26: I'm not so sure, as Isim is being asked to do something it can't.  It might simply need an error message...

Comment: @MartinThompson: It doesn't seem to matter, I've opened a webcase with Xilinx to see what they think.

Answer (score 2):

At initialisation time, `test_char_i` has the value `integer'low`, which doesn't map to a `character` - Modelsim 10.0 reports:

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3390) Result ?(-2147483648) of attribute 'VAL is out of range NUL (0) to 'ÿ' (255).
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Process: /my_entity/line__15 File: attr.vhd
# Fatal error in Architecture my_arc at attr.vhd line 15
#
```

If I make `test_char_i` a `natural`, so that it initialises to `0`, things work as you expect (in Modelsim at least, haven't tried iSim)

Comment: Indeed, according to the standard, the sensitivity of the equivalent process is `test_char_i`. So iSim does not follow the standard and ModelSim does.

Comment: Making `test_char_i` a natural doesn't change the result, but that'll be handy for the bug report.

Comment: What would happen if I tried to synthesise such a thing, then?

Comment: @detly: I doubt it works, but maybe it depends on what you do with your `character` (do a `printf` ? ;-) ). You should carefully distinguish between legal VHDL and its behavior according to the standard **and** synthesizable VHDL and its interpretation by synthesis tools. I think the kind of code you have shown should be restricted to non-synthesized modules such as testbenches.

Comment: @wap26: I disagree - that should be perfectly valid synthesis code. Just because there's some intermediate signals, you shouldn't be stopped by any synthesizer I know from converting an 8-bit vector to a character.

Comment: @wap26: In this case, it is for a testbench. But I might want to synthesise something, some day, that turns a `std_logic_vector` into an ASCII character.

Comment: @martin: Ok, but I wouldn't do this myself. `character` is just an enumerated type like any other one after all. But I would not recommend using the `'val` or `'pos` attributes of an enumerated in synthesis, because the encoding is subject to optimization.

Comment: @detly: just out of curiosity, what would you do with your `character`? (I'm not saying it's a bad idea).

Comment: @wap26 - Oh I didn't really have anything concrete in mind. In the testbench case it's just for debugging. In a synthesisable entity, maybe to make a `case` statement more readable?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that a bare signal assignment will be updated concurrently if any signal on the right hand side changes. In other words, it's equivalent to a process that is sensitive to all signals involved in the assignment.

That's correct.

> Why doesn't test_char_c get updated in the first instance?

It does.

A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a monitor process that will report all value updates on `test_char_c`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity my_entity is
end entity;

architecture my_arc of my_entity is
    signal test_char   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal test_char_c : character;
    signal test_char_i : natural; -- integer;
begin
    test_char   <= "01001010";
    test_char_i <= to_integer(unsigned(test_char));
    test_char_c <= character'val(test_char_i);

    process (test_char_c)
    begin
        report "test_char_c = " & character'image(test_char_c);
    end process;
end architecture my_arc;
```

Note the change to the declaration of `test_char_i` to overcome the default initial value (INTEGER'LOW) causing a bound check failure as reported by Martin Thompson.

This was analyzed, elaborated and simulated using a -1993 compliant VHDL tool:

> ghdl -r my_entity
>   ../../src/ieee/numeric_std-body.v93:2098:7:@0ms:(assertion warning):   NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0
>   my_entity.vhdl:19:9:@0ms:(report note): test_char_c = nul
>   my_entity.vhdl:19:9:@0ms:(report note): test_char_c = 'J'

The assertion warning from package numeric_std is caused by the `test_char` default intial value of "UUUUUUUU".

The first reported `test_char_c` value is the NUL you reported and occurs because the initial value of `test_char_i` is 0 (mapping to NUL).

The second is in response to the concurrent simple signal assignment to `test_char` resulting in an update of `test_char_i` in turn resulting in an update of `test_char_c`(and resuming the monitor process). It reflects the assigned bit string to `test_char` with a value x"4A" (corresponding to the character 'J').

If instead of the shown monitor process you were to have an assertion statement of the form:

```
    assert test_char_c /= NUL
        report "test_char_c = " & character'image(test_char_c);
```

You'd find that only the first report statement is displayed because an assertion statement condition is evaluated and when found false asserts.

Likewise if the "/=" in the condition were changed to "=" only the second report statement would be displayed (showing 'J').

Without providing a MCVe your problem can't be duplicated (or blamed on the then nascent ISIM).